# Would the British say "clearance" or "clearing"?

Tags: meaning, differences, british-english

What is the definition of *clearance*?  Is it the word of choice to describe a clear spot in the jungle to land a helicopter? Or would *clearing* be used to describe this?

Comment: Both clearance and clearing have a number of meanings in British and other versions of English. Did you look up the words in a dictionary?

Comment: The usage of the words themselves in BrE and AmE is similar, see the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clearance%2Cclearing&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclearance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclearing%3B%2Cc0). But 'clearing' is how BrE refers to a treeless area in a jungle. 'Clearance' is most often encountered, I would say, in the expression 'clearance sale' which is when a business closes down and sells its stock at cut-price. It also refers to the removal of all the balls in a game of snooker.

Comment: @DJClayworth Surely it all depends on context. Also clearance is a noun while clearing is a verb. I hope we cleared that one up, what?

Comment: @PeterPoint But _clearing_ is also used as a noun in the very specific case of a cleared space in a forest or wood [see the ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clearing) which was the context of the OPs question. A forest _clearance_ would be a project to remove trees from a large area and the clearance would be the process, not the result. For an historical equivalent see the Encyclopedia Brittanica entry for the 18th century Scottish [Highland Clearances](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Highland-Clearances) which cleared the human population rather than vegetation.

Comment: may an American answer using  AmE?

Comment: @BoldBen You are quite correct. Mea culpa! I think I better clear off now.

Answer (score 1):

For the sense of a (relatively) clear patch in a jungle, the word is "[clearing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clearance+in+the+jungle%2Cclearing+in+the+jungle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclearing%20in%20the%20jungle%3B%2Cc0)", not "clearance".